# Having issue with colorbox with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm having an issue with colorbox when I have loaded content via AJAX.  I use the normal code that is given from the docs:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".lightbox").colorbox();
     });
```

It works when on this page:

http://www.mdlab.com/executive-personnel/

But not when I load in the content from AJAX (circled in red):

[image]
http://www.mdlab.com/testing-menu/

I'm really stumped and this first time I have ever tried colorbox, so any help is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is, that webpage is already "ready", 
ajax request are small single requests, $(document) object dont know about them.
add

```
$(".lightbox").colorbox();
```

into showTestList.js to line 23, where you process the response.

And little help: look for jQuery.ajax functions :)

Comment: I doing this off of someone else's code and he doesn't know jQuery and refuses to learn it. Otherwise I would use that function. :(